# Why does Oracle SQL update query return "invalid identifier" on existing column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have an update query for an Oracle SQL db. Upon execution the query returns `ORA-00904: "t1"."sv_id": invalid identifier`

So, why do I get an "invalid identifier" error message although the column exists?

Here is the complete query (replaced actual table and column names by dummies in np++)

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 SET (type) =
    CASE
        WHEN
            ((SELECT COUNT(dateCheck.id) FROM table_2 dateCheck
              WHERE dateCheck.s_id = t1.s_id AND dateCheck.sv_id = t1.sv_id) = 0)
        THEN
            (SELECT sv.type FROM table_3 sv WHERE sv.id = t1.sv_id)
        ELSE
            (SELECT type FROM
                (SELECT d.type as type FROM table_2 d
                 WHERE d.s_id = t1.s_id AND d.sv_id = t1.sv_id
                 ORDER BY d.creationTimestamp ASC)
                 WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
        END
```

Now I don't understand why that error occurs.

Here is what I already know:

- The Queries in the `CASE` statement work when executed separately, provided they are wrapped into a query that provides table_1 t1 for sure.
- `t1.s_id` seems to work since oracle doesn't complain about that. When i change it to a column that really doesn't exist, oracle starts complaining about that non existent column before returning something about `t1.sv_id`. So somehow the alias might work, although I'm not sure about it.
- I'm 100% sure that the column `t1.sv_id` exists and no typo was made. Executed a query on `t1` directly and doublechecked everything in notepad by marking all occurences.
- An (completely unrelated) update query like the following works as well (note the alias `t1` is used in the select query). Don't assume table_1/2 to be the same as in the update query above, just reused the names. This should just illustrate that I successfully used an alias in an update query before.

  ```
  update table_1 t1 set (t2_id) = (select id from table_2 t2 where t1.id = t2.t1_id)
  ```

### UPDATE

Thx a lot for pointing me to the "you don't have access to alises in deeper suquery layers" issue. That got me on track again pretty fast.

So here is the query I ended up with. This seems to work fine. Eliminates the acces to t1 in the deeper layers and selects the oldest row, so that the same result should be returned from the query I expected from the original query in the ELSE part.

```
        UPDATE table_1 t1 SET (type) =
        CASE
           WHEN
            ((SELECT COUNT(dateCheck.id) FROM table_2 dateCheck
              WHERE dateCheck.s_id = t1.s_id AND dateCheck.sv_id = t1.sv_id) = 0)
           THEN
            (SELECT sv.type FROM table_3 sv WHERE sv.id = t1.sv_id)
           ELSE
                (SELECT d.type as type FROM table_2 d
                 WHERE d.s_id = t1.s_id 
                    AND d.sv_id = t1.sv_id 
                    AND d.creation = (SELECT MIN(id.creation) FROM table_2 id 
                                      WHERE d.s_id = id.s_id AND d.sv_id = id.sv_id))
        END
```

Comment: It's having `t1.sv_id` referenced two layers deep, in the `SELECT FROM (SELECT ...`, that it doesn't like. Table aliases can be referenced that deep. Your second bullet is confusing though, I'd still expect the parser to hit `t1.sv_id` first and complain about that, not even seeing your really-invalid column name. Unless you changed the `t` to something else too.

Comment: ... or you changed the `t1.s_id` in the `when` clause; but when that is valid it's the `t1.sv_id` in the `else` that's throwing the error. Check the reported line numbers in both cases.

Comment: The count check implies there won't always be matching data in table_2; but will there always be matching data in table_3, even if there is a match in table_2?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, there is always data available in table_3. So an option for me would also be to execute the query in THEN first and execute the ELSE afterwards. Since the query is meant for data migration, performance and stuff would not be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference a table alias in a subquery of a subquery; the alias doesn't apply (or doesn't exist, or isn't in scope, depending on how you prefer to look at it). With the code you posted the error is reported against line 11 character 24, which is:

```
        (SELECT type FROM
            (SELECT d.type as type FROM table_2 d
             WHERE d.s_id = t1.s_id AND d.sv_id = t1.sv_id
                                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

If you change the t1.s_id reference on the same line to something invalid then the error doesn't change and is still reported as `ORA-00904: "T1"."SV_ID": invalid identifier`. But if you change the same reference on line 5 instead to something like

```
        ((SELECT COUNT(dateCheck.id) FROM table_2 dateCheck
          WHERE dateCheck.s_id = t1.s_idXXX AND dateCheck.sv_id = t1.sv_id) = 0)
```

... then the error changes to `ORA-00904: "T1"."S_IDXXX": invalid identifier`. This is down to how the statement is being parsed. In your original version the subquery in the `WHEN` clause is value, and you only break it by changing that identifier. The subquery in the `ELSE` is also OK. But the *nested* subquery in the `ELSE` has the problem, and changing the `t1.s_id` in that doesn't make any difference because the parser reads that part of the statement backwards (I don't know, or can't remember, why!).

So you have to eliminate the nested subquery. A general approach would be to make the whole `CASE` an inline view which you can then join using `s_id` and `sv_id`, but that's complicated as there may be no matching `table_2` record (based on your count); and there may be no `s_id` value to match against as that isn't being checked in `table_3`.

It isn't clear if there will always be a `table_3` record even then there is a `table_2` record, or if they're mutually exclusive. If I've understood what the `CASE` is doing then I *think* you can use an outer join between those two tables and compare the combined data with the row you're updating, but because of that ambiguity it needs to be a full outer join. I think.

Here's a stab at using that construct with a `MERGE` instead of an update.

```
MERGE INTO table_1 t1
USING (
  SELECT t2.s_id,
    coalesce(t2.sv_id, t3.id) as sv_id,
    coalesce(t2.type, t3.type) as type,
    row_number() over (partition by t2.s_id, t2.sv_id
      order by t2.creationtimestamp) as rn
  FROM table_2 t2
  FULL OUTER JOIN table_3 t3
  ON t3.id = t2.sv_id
) tmp
ON ((tmp.s_id is null OR tmp.s_id = t1.s_id) AND tmp.sv_id = t1.sv_id AND tmp.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.type = tmp.type;
```

If there will always be a `table_3` record then you could use that as the driver and have a left outer join to `table_2` instead, but hard to tell which might be appropriate. So this is really just a starting point.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/416a5/1) with some made-up data that I believe would have hit both branches of your case. More realistic data would expose the flaws and misunderstandings, and suggest a more robust (or just more correct) approach...

Answer (score 0):

Your query and your analysis seems sound to me. I have no solution but a few things you can try to maybe trigger something that explains this odd behavior:

- Quote the column (just in case it happens to be a SQL keyword).
- Use `table_1.sv_id` - this works as long as the whole query contains this table only once.
- Make sure that the alias `t1` exists only once
- Run the query with a query tool like [SQuirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) - the tool can examine the exact position where Oracle reports the problem. Maybe it's in a different place of the query than you think
- Check `()` and make sure they are around the parts where they should be.
- Swap the order of expressions around `=`